# Magic Links Enhancer

Tags: script, comments

This userscript adds a way to quickly link to posts, help pages, privileges and links across the Stack Exchange sites.

It uses [@M'vy's idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92067/260841) of having a basic format of `[SITE:type:id]`, and works the same way across the network.

> Where
>
> - `SITE` is SF, SO, SU, meta, metaSU with default to the current site
> - `type` can be user, post, faq with default to post
> - `id` can be the id of a post, of an user and anchor a HTML anchor like in the FAQ, or a comment, or a anwser.
>
> You can only use default values from the left. If you specify SITE you have to specify all.

(quoted from his post)

`SITE` can be `su`, `so`, `sf`, or any other SE site by using their API sitename (the thing before `.stackexchange.com`), eg. [`pets`], `[chess]` will expand to the link to that site.

`type` (followed by `anchor`) can be `user` (followed by user id), `post` (followed by post id), `help` (followed by help page name in URL), or `priv` (followed by priv name in URL).

### Install it from [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/shu8/6c7979a4e5861c2e234301cbfa504628/raw/6267555bfffff5ee01476026dcbf575da88498ab/magicLinkEnhancer.user.js)

(or [view the source](https://gist.github.com/shu8/6c7979a4e5861c2e234301cbfa504628))

---

Examples (if posted in a comment on Meta Stack Exchange):

- `[274240]` => `[Adding magic link for Meta Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274240)`
- `[so:post:1732348]` => `[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348)`
- `[so:post:1732454]` => `[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)`
- `[meta.so:post:321111]` => `[How to help less-skilled developers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321111)`
- `[user:260841]` => `[ᔕᖺᘎᕊ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/260841/%e1%94%95%e1%96%ba%e1%98%8e%e1%95%8a)`
- `[pets:priv:trusted-user]` => `[trusted user](//pets.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)`
- `[stackapps:help:dont-ask]` => `[Help Center](//stackapps.com/help/dont-ask)`
- `[help:dont-ask]` => `[Help Center](http://meta.stackexchange.com)`
- `[meta.so]` => `[Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com)`